# Microsoft Visual C++ 8.0 compiler error which occurs when the C++ class API and /or the number of C++ classes in a DLL becomes too large

Tags: visual-c++-2008

I was wondering if anyone knew what the number of the Microsoft Visual C++ 8.0 compiler error which occurs when a C++ class API and /or the number of C++ classes in a DLL becomes too large.
   Thank you for your help.

Comment: LNK1248: Linker Tools Error LNK1248
Visual Studio 2012 Other Versions  Visual Studio 2010 Visual Studio 2008 Visual Studio 2005 Visual Studio .NET 2003 0 out of 2 rated this helpful - Rate this topic 
image size ('size') exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)

The linker determined that the size of the output file will exceed the largest possible size for a program image. You may want to make your program into multiple DLLs. For more information on the program executable (PE), see the article "Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format" in the MSDN Library.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is:

That would probably most likely be Microsoft Visual C++ compiler C1002 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c9e6fs6b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): 
"compiler is out of heap space in pass 2"

Fatal Error C1002
Visual Studio 2005 Other Versions  Visual Studio 2012 Visual Studio 2010 Visual Studio 2008 Visual Studio .NET 2003 1 out of 3 rated this helpful - Rate this topic 
Error Message 
compiler is out of heap space in pass 2

The compiler ran out of dynamic memory space during its second pass, probably due to a program with too many symbols or complex expressions.

To fix by using the following possible solutions
1.Divide the source file into several smaller files.

2.Break expressions into smaller subexpressions.

3.Remove other programs or drivers that consume memory

Please let me know your opinionof this proposed answer.

---

### the solution to this problem  i was told this morning is to close the Visual Studio C++ 2008 environment and then restart ii up again.

Answer (score 0):

### Shown below is the latest answer I received to the Stack Overflow question:

### Microsoft Visual C++ 8.0 compiler error which occurs when the C++ class API and /or the number of C++ classes in a DLL becomes too large

"the compiler's input objects are source files, not dll's. the dll is output of the linker. i never have seen a source file that was too big for compilation. the biggest file i can remember had about 50,000 lines. it probably included header files of same or greater total size.

if your system is low on heap memory it is more likely that the linker would report problems or error because of this. in my opinion it is only a rare chance to happen on a modern system. you also could/should upgrade to newer version of visual studio, for example visual studio 2012 (vc11) is 7 years younger than your compiler. if you were developing on windows xp you should go to vs2008 (vc9) which is more stable than vc8"

Comment: Could someone verify the above answer for me? Thank you very much.